# Lefschetz fixed point theorem in terms of cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fixed-point-theorems, geometric-topology

In the some books and webpages for the definition of lefschetz fixed point writer use $ \mathbb{Q}$ as a coefficient

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem)
 and some writer use $ \mathbb{Z}$.

Does it make any differences to use different modules ? In addition, if we use $\mathbb{Q}$ it is easy to formulate lefschetz fixed point in terms of cohomology by using universal coefficient theorem but is it easy when we use $ \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: In general how is the trace defined on $H^*(X, \mathbb Z)$?

Comment: Is not it the same as definion on homology.Trace of matrices of linear map between modules .

Comment: In general the trace of an endomorphism of a module is only defined if that module is finitely generated projective (the obvious definition, where you write down the sum of the diagonals of a matrix, only works in the even more restricted case that the module is finitely generated free). So if the homology or cohomology has torsion it's unclear what to do (the answer is to ignore the torsion). That's why it's convenient to work over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I see ,by using  $\mathbb{Q}$ you have killed torsion part of homology with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficient.What about formulation of Lefschetz fixed point in terms of  cohomology if i use $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: You run into exactly the same problem: there might be torsion in the cohomology too.